# How to sum variables from file in Bash

Tags: bash, arithmetic

I need to sum numbers from a file line by line.

The file:

```
1.0
0.46
0.67
```

I want to sum, then divide 3.

I currently have:

```
while IFS= read -r var
do
   x=$(($var + $x)) | bc -l
done < "file.txt"
echo "$x / 3"
```

My error:

```
-bash: 1.0 + 0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0 + 0")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bash/shell arithmetic can't handle floating point arithmetic. You can accomplish your task using `awk`:

```
awk '{sum= sum+$1} END {print sum/3}' file
```

This will read through your file and add each line to `sum`. After it completes reading the file, it will print `sum` divided by 3.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun

```
$ paste -sd+ file | dc -e2k0 -f- -e+3/p
.71
```

---

Here we're using the `dc` [reverse Polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) calculator: to sum the numbers we want to write them as

```
1.0 0.46 + 0.67 +
```

however it's easier to prime the stack with zero (`-e0`) and make it

```
0 1.0+0.46+0.67 +
```

since the body of the sum can then be generated by a simple `paste command`:

```
$ paste -sd+ file
1.0+0.46+0.67
```

Lastly we need the final postfix `+` for the sum and the postfix division which we can write in another `-e` command (not forgetting to print the final result) as `-e+3/p`.

The last wrinkle is that although `dc` can work in arbitrary precision, division defaults to a precision of 0 and hence will return an integer result. We can change that using the `2k` command which pushes `2` to the stack and then pops it and uses the result to set the precision.

Putting it all together:

```
paste -sd+ file | dc -e2k0 -f- -e+3/p
```

Comment: This answer would be more valuable with a little explanation

Comment: @Bernhard thanks - I've added some

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x=0
while IFS= read -r var; do
    x="$(echo "$var + $x" | bc -l)"
done < "file.txt"
echo "$x / 3" | bc -l
```

1. `x` was not defined.
2. You need an `echo` for `bc` to work (not mixed bash arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

For summing the numbers, [`numsum` from the `num-utils` package](https://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/index.phtml) will do exactly that in one go:

```
x=$(numsum file.txt)
```

It is happy to deal with decimal numbers.

For the division afterwards `numprocess` from the same package can help:

```
numsum file.txt | numprocess /%3/
```

`%` is how `numprocess` represents division, and the slashes are an oddity of its argument structure.